# Count Divided by a Count

Tags: t-sql, count, sum

How do you divide a count by another count.  I have seen a few different methods but I am unable to get them to work for my purposes.  The code that I am working on currently is:

```
Select(select COUNT(lUsers) 
        FROM Tlocation
        WHERE dLastUpdated IS NOT NULL 
            AND dRemovalDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE()) and GETDATE())
                /
            (SELECT COUNT(lUsers) 
        FROM Tlocation 
        WHERE dLastUpdated < GETDATE() 
            AND dRemovalDate IS NULL OR dRemovalDate > GETDATE())
```

But this just returns a 0 every time.

Comment: Please run each subselect alone and check what values it's trying to divide by. It could be caused by the top subselect always returns 0

Comment: Top returns 1562 and the bottom returns 92825

Comment: Oh. Decimals it is, then. One moment :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the value is less than an INT (which COUNT() returns). Here's how you could do it:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT 1562 
    )
    /
    CAST(
        (
            SELECT 92825
        )
        AS DECIMAL(20, 10)
    )
;
```

Or for your query:

```
Select(select COUNT(lUsers) 
        FROM Tlocation
        WHERE dLastUpdated IS NOT NULL 
            AND dRemovalDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE()) and GETDATE())
                /
            CAST(
                    (SELECT COUNT(lUsers) 
                FROM Tlocation 
                WHERE dLastUpdated < GETDATE() 
                    AND dRemovalDate IS NULL OR dRemovalDate > GETDATE())
            AS DECIMAL(20, 10)
            )
;
```